# Перегрузка метода, где в качестве параметра объект одного из классов-наследников

Tags: java, ооп, наследование, перегрузка-операторов

Есть абстрактный класс `MyClass` от которого наследуются `MyClassA` И `MyClassB`.

Есть фабрика, которая в зависимости от принимаемых параметров метода `create()` возвращает объект класса `MyClassA` или `MyClassB`.

И есть перегруженный для `MyClassA` и `MyClassB` метод `Foo()`.

Но в итоге компилятор говорит, что метод `Foo()` не применим для аргументов класса `MyClass`. Что я сделал не так?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Factory fact = new Factory();
        MyClass test = fact.create(10, 10, "Hello");
        fact.Foo(test);
    }
}

abstract class MyClass {
    public int mParam;

    public MyClass(int param) {
        mParam = param;
    }
}

class MyClassA extends MyClass {
    public int mParam2;

    public MyClassA(int param, int param2) {
        super(param);
        mParam2 = param2;
    }
}

class MyClassB extends MyClass {
    public String mParam3;

    public MyClassB(int param, String param3) {
        super(param);
        mParam3 = param3;
    }
}

class Factory {
    public MyClass create(int param, int param2, String param3) {
        if (param < 3) {
            return new MyClassA(param, param2);
        } else if (param > 3) {
            return new MyClassB(param, param3);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void Foo(MyClassA obj) {
        System.out.println(obj.mParam2);
    }

    public void Foo(MyClassB obj) {
        System.out.println(obj.mParam3);
    }
}
```

Comment: это разумно. во-первых, выбор конкретного перегруженного метода выполняется на этапе компиляции в байт-код, во-вторых, нет гарантии, что список наследников `MyClass` исчерпывается `MyClassA` и `MyClassB`. Было бы, конечно, неплохо, если бы javac посчитал константы и заменил весь `main` на `println("Hello");`, но увы.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете вызвать метод с другим типом параметра, если такого метода не существует. При перегрузке методов вы можете менять типы и количество параметров, а при вызове метода с таким именем четко указывать типы и количество параметров, которые принимаются методом. Количество параметров определяется сигнатурой метода, т.е. не является еще одним параметром, чтобы было понятно.

```
fact.Foo(test);
```

чтобы исправить ошибку в этой строке надо переписать

```
fact.Foo((MyClassB)test);
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас методы `Foo()` принимают аргументы либо `MyClassA`, либо `MyClassB`, а вы подаете на вход объект типа `MyClass`. Я думаю ваш в вопрос в том, **почему это не работает, ведь это предок этих классов?**
Дело в том, что наследники расширяют функционал родителя. То есть в наследнике есть всё, что есть в родителе плюс еще что-то дополнительно (методы, свойства). 
Рассмотрим на примере животных:
Есть базовый класс - `Animal`. `Animal` умеет `eat()` и `sleep()`. И есть наследники - `Cat` и `Bird`. Помимо того, что эти наследники умеют так же `eat()` и `sleep()`, они обладают дополнительными способностями, у кота это `haunt()`, у птицы `fly()`.
И теперь смотрите, в чем суть. У вас метод `Foo()` принимает на вход либо `Cat`, либо `Bird`. Внутри этих методов мы можете использовать функционал методы наследников (`haunt()` в случае с `Cat` и `fly()` в случае с `Bird`), но в коде вы передаете `Animal`, а `Animal` не умеет ни `fly()`, ни `haunt()`.
Вот чтобы такого не дай бог не произошло, компилятор не дает вам использовать предка в тех местах, где ожидаются наследники.